# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Need aid with a simple command-line program in Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

The goal is to make a program where the user enters in a number as a command-line argument. The integer entered will correspond with the Fibonacci number at that position in the sequence, like an array. 
The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(fibonacci(x));
    }
    public static int fibonacci(int n)  {
        if(n == 0)
            return 0;
        else if(n <= 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the prog

Comment: Show command line arguments you were using...

Comment: call the prog using java Main 12 and see if it works

Answer (score 4):

You miss to pass a commandline parameter, so you get an Exception here:

```
 int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

You should check first before accassing the argument:

```
if (args.length>0){
   int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
} else {
   //print usage
}
```

Comment: More to It before Parsing It to Integer check for is argument a Number to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code with command line, you need to pass the arguments as follows:

```
java <ClassName> <arg1>
```

In your case, for example:

```
java Main 10
```